# rubyでハッシュから日付のオブジェクトを作る方法

Tags: ruby

```
date_hash = {
  :year => 2015,
  :month => 12,
  :day => 15,
}
```

これを`Date.new(date_hash)`みたいな事をして日付オブジェクトを作りたいのですが、
Rubyらしくかけますか?

Answer (score 2):

```
[19] pry(main)> Date.new(*date_hash.values)
=> #<Date: 2015-12-15 ((2457372j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

こんな感じでしょうか？

## 追記 2015-12-12 11:18

`values`は hash の基本的なインスタンスメソッドです。
検索するとすぐに出てきますので、ご自分でご確認ください。
[ruby hash values - Google 検索](https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=ruby%20hash#q=ruby+hash+values)

`*` は検索性が低いので、引用します。
[メソッド呼び出し(super・ブロック付き・yield) (Ruby 2.2.0)](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/2.2.0/doc/spec=2fcall.html)

> 最後の引数の直前に * がついている場合、その引数の値が展開されて 渡されます。展開はメソッド to_a を経由して行なわれます。つまり:
>
> ```
> foo(1,*[2,3,4]) 
> foo(1,*[])`
> ```
>
> は、それぞれ
>
> ```
> foo(1,2,3,4) 
> foo(1)
> ```
>
> と同じです。

つまり、

```
[20] pry(main)> date_hash.values
=> [2015, 12, 15]
```

であり、配列のまま渡すとエラーになるので、

```
[24] pry(main)> Date.new([2015, 12, 15])
NoMethodError: undefined method `<' for [2015, 12, 15]:Array
from (pry):28:in `new'
```

展開して渡しているということです。
下記2つは同じ意味ですから。

```
[25] pry(main)> Date.new(*[2015, 12, 15])
[26] pry(main)> Date.new(2015, 12, 15)
```

`ruby splat` で検索すると良いかもしれません。

### 補足

tmtms さんのご指摘の通り、`values_at` の方がより頑健になります。
`values` と `values_at` の違いはお調べになると良いかもしれません。

Comment: ありがとうございます!!`*`と`values`がいったい何なのかわからないのですが、説明していただくことは可能でしょうか。

Comment: `date_hash.values` だと `date_hash` の生成方法に依存してしまうので、`values_at` を使った方がいいと思います。
`Date.new(*date_hash.values_at(:year, :month, :day))`